# Convert output of MySQL query to utf8

Tags: mysql, sql, utf-8

I have a table in my database and I want run a query like

```
SELECT column1, column2 FROM my_table WHERE my_condition;
```

but I want the mysql to return the `column2` in utf8 encoding. Is it any function in mysql to do such task? What is that?

Comment: Try `SELECT column1, CONVERT(column2 USING utf8)...`

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can use CAST and CONVERT to switch between different types of encodings. See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-convert.html

```
SELECT column1, CONVERT(column2 USING utf8)
FROM my_table 
WHERE my_condition;
```

Comment: how to do this for `select *` as this is an syntax error `select convert(* using utf8)`

Comment: Hey mate, I believe you can't use the wildcard character and have to convert columns individually:
`SELECT CONVERT(mycol1 USING utf8), CONVERT(mycol2 USING utf8)`

Comment: The link in your post now gives a 404, but I think the correct link is now https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html

Answer (score 50):

```
SELECT CONVERT(CAST(column as BINARY) USING utf8) as column FROM table
```

Comment: Thanks you saved my day :)

Comment: Thanks ! Save my day to !

Comment: CAST to BINARY saved me! You rock!

Comment: Casting the column to binary before converting to UTF-8 solved it for me too.

Comment: this did not work for me. I had to do it the other way, CAST on the outside

Answer (score 29):

Addition:

When using the MySQL **client library**, then you should prevent a conversion back to your *connection's default charset*. (see `mysql_set_character_set()`[[1]](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-set-character-set.html))

In this case, use an additional cast to binary:

```
SELECT column1, CAST(CONVERT(column2 USING utf8) AS binary)
FROM my_table
WHERE my_condition;
```

Otherwise, the `SELECT` statement converts to utf-8, but your client library converts it back to a (potentially different) default connection charset.

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you. 
CONVERT(CAST( did not work for me.

Comment: Same there, the accepted answer with convert only didn't work for me, this one did, thanks.

Answer (score 13):

I have used next code for LATIN1 (or your db's charset) to UTF8 problems :

```
SELECT column1,
       CONVERT(CAST(CONVERT(column2 USING LATIN1) AS BINARY) USING UTF8) AS column2
  FROM my_table
 WHERE my_condition
```

It converts from LATIN1 to BINARY, then to UTF8, because straight from LATIN1 to UTF8 might not work.