# Python mysqlclient and data on two different servers

Tags: python, mysql, unicode, encoding

On my local machine (MacOS) I have MariaDB 10.4, Python 3.7.4 and mysqlclient 1.4.4. 
On remote server (FreeBSD) I have MySQL 5.2, Python 3.7.2 and mysqlclient 1.4.4.

Database is in `utf8` encoding on the both machines.

My script using query with CONCAT, like:

```
SELECT IF(agreements.date <> '0000-00-00', CONCAT(agreements.date, ' 00:00:00 +0300'), '').....
```

Why on my local machine class of values in resulting tuple is always **STR**, but on remote server class is **STR** or **BYTES** and each column value where I used mysql's CONCAT function starts with b'...' and has **BYTES** class. 
I know that I can decode byte values (b.decode()) and leave other str values as is

```
data = cursor.fetchall()
l = [list(x) for x in data]
for d in l:
    for idx, vals in enumerate(d):
        if isinstance(vals, bytes):
            d[idx] = vals.decode()
```

but why did this happen - MySQL version??

I see two ways: decode via Python as I posted or use mysql's `CONVERT <column> USING utf8` function as @Joe McKenna said. But why shouldn't I do this on a local computer I don't know :( MySQL server versions are different, but charset config is same.

Example script:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
# coding: utf8


import MySQLdb

connection = MySQLdb.Connection(
    user='root',
    passwd='password',
    db='billing',
    host='localhost',
    charset='utf8'
)

cursor = connection.cursor()


cursor.execute("SELECT '', CONCAT(birthdate, ' TEST!!!!!') from accounts")
for d in cursor.fetchall():
    print(d)

cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

Output:

```
('', b'1958-11-11 TEST!!!!!')
('', b'0000-00-00 TEST!!!!!')
('', b'0000-00-00 TEST!!!!!')
('', b'0000-00-00 TEST!!!!!')
('', b'0000-00-00 TEST!!!!!')
('', b'0000-00-00 TEST!!!!!')
('', b'0000-00-00 TEST!!!!!')
('', b'0000-00-00 TEST!!!!!')
('', b'1950-10-09 TEST!!!!!')
```

UPDATE:

Result of `mysql> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';`

Localhost:

```
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value              |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8               |
| character_set_connection | utf8               |
| character_set_database   | utf8               |
| character_set_filesystem | binary             |
| character_set_results    | utf8               |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_system     | utf8               |
| collation_connection     | utf8_general_ci    |
| collation_database       | utf8_general_ci    |
| collation_server         | utf8mb4_general_ci |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
```

Remote server:

```
+--------------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name            | Value           |
+--------------------------+-----------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8            |
| character_set_connection | utf8            |
| character_set_database   | utf8            |
| character_set_filesystem | binary          |
| character_set_results    | utf8            |
| character_set_server     | utf8            |
| character_set_system     | utf8            |
| collation_connection     | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_database       | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_server         | utf8_general_ci |
+--------------------------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embed the output type in all queries with 'convert' keyword like in this post:

---

[Convert output of MySQL query to utf8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16051369/convert-output-of-mysql-query-to-utf8)

---

SELECT column1, CONVERT(column2 USING utf8)
FROM my_table 
WHERE my_condition;

---

Or you can use the 'alter' command to change each column in the db to the datatype you want:

---

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33365/tell-mysql-to-start-using-utf-8-encoding-without-convert-toing-it

---

Comment: Thanks for Your answer, but why i should convert output? My database is already in utf8, tables are also in utf8. And if I doing query without CONCAT, I get's normal data. Is CONCAT function returns binary data? If so - why on macOS it is string, not bytes. P.S. CONVERT(column USING utf8) of course works.

Comment: The results of the mysql concat function vary with the arguments datatype as follows:
***
• Returns the string that results from concatenating the arguments.
• Returns a nonbinary string, if all arguments are nonbinary strings.
• Returns a binary string, if the arguments include any binary strings.
• If the argument is numeric, it is converted to its equivalent nonbinary string form.
• Returns NULL if any argument is NULL.
*** adding a 'convert' on the outside of the 'concat' gives more consistency in return data type.