# SQL query- converting encoding to UTF-8

Tags: sql, etl

I am querying from a SQL table using an ETL tool (Alteryx) and two column contains special characters like "á" , "é", "ő" but they appear as &#250 ;, etc. Looks to me that need to convert those columns to  UTF-8 (?) by casting and converting, but all my query runs to an error.

[Convert output of MySQL query to utf8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16051369/convert-output-of-mysql-query-to-utf8) - used this thread previously

Can someone help me what I'm doing wrog here?

thanks,
WM

Comment: You  need to show a sample query that you are using.  Otherwise it is difficult to give you an answer.

Comment: SELECT CONVERT(CAST(column as BINARY) USING utf8) as column FROM table  - this is the one I was trying to use

Comment: Are you are certain that if you inspect your database directly (from Myql workbench for instance), you can see the proper character 'à'?  (just to check that the problem is not happening when saving into the database)

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL server management studio writing the actual query, but neither there nor in Alteryx the character "á" is appears as "á" rather it's character code.