# MySQL Non English characters as?

Tags: mysql

In MySQL database table, I am inserting non English (Chinese/Japanese) characters and it was getting inserted inserted as **????**. I fixed this issue. But I want older data to be converted into actual language format.

Is there any solution for this ?

Comment: Please read this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through  If you still have problems, you need to [edit] your question to show various character sets and collations.

Comment: @O.Jones the shared link doesn't mention about converting older data. For new setup it is ok.

Comment: In what character set (or with what collation) is the older data stored? The same question applies to the newer data. There are all sorts of complexities, mentioned in "UTF-8 all the way through" : What's the character set of the connection? What software are you using to display the offending data?

Comment: only in mysql editor when i select data from table then I get ??? for older data.

Comment: If it's already `???` in the data table, what kind of function that you can use in a query to return the original non-English characters?

Comment: @FaNo_FN I am also looking for the same. Actually this is the question.

Comment: My mistake, I understand it incorrectly. I'm not really sure myself but referring to a few methods I've found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16051369/convert-output-of-mysql-query-to-utf8), I'm afraid that once the value is already `???` it will [stay that way](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4a3eec91f863323b14d90c00e7282a59).